# Why is my listview unclickable?

Tags: android, listview, click

I have a Listview of layouts that prints out some information, for some reason when I click on each element it does not highlight, telling me that my listview is unclickable. Here is my code.

```
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.imtrackinglistview);
    refreshList(response, lv);
       static final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    private void refreshList(String response, ListView lv) {
    // removes the list and rebuilds it will choose different response
    // string to get the refreshed times
    list.removeAll(list);
    SpecialAdapter adapter = new SpecialAdapter(this, list,
        R.layout.imtracking_row_text,
       new String[] { "name", "location" }, new int[] {
       R.id.tvImtrackingName, R.id.tvImtrackingLocation });
       lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The adapter is so that I can switch between background colors.

```
public class SpecialAdapter extends SimpleAdapter{
private int[] colors=new int[]{0x30FF0000, 0x300000FF};
public SpecialAdapter (AnotherlistviewActivity context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list, int resource, String[] from, int[] to){
    super(context, list, resource, from, to);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    View view=super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
    int colorPos=position%colors.length;
    view.setBackgroundColor(colors[colorPos]);
    return view;
}
  }
```

I find it strange that suddenly my listview is unclickable, hopefully someone can figure out why this is. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want do something onclick then u must go for adding setOnClickListener(lv). Sometimes you may not know that ListView is clickable because it color doesnot change when clicked.

Comment: This worried me for a while because on my test listview everything was clickable, yet for some reason in my app listview suddenly I didn't see the color change so I assumed that something was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This might work.

```
list.setClickable(true);
```

Edit: You might also need

```
list.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: I tried this and even put it in the xml but still no luck  <ListView   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/imtrackinglistview" android:clickable="true" android:paddingTop="10dp"></ListView>

Comment: Hi, I just tried setEnabled and it still doesn't work. My listview shows everything properly but it looks like a picture and doesn't seem to be clickable

Answer (score 1):

This may work:

```
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setClickable(true);
lv.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Did you try lv.setClickable(true) instead of list.setClickable(true)?